# GQL does not work for GET paramters for keys

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gqlquery

I am trying to compare the key to filter results in GQL in Python but the direct comparison nor typecasting to int works. Therefore, I am forced to make a work around as mentioned in the uncommented lines below. Any clues?

```
row = self.request.get("selectedrow")
#mydbobject = DbModel.gql("WHERE key=:1", row).fetch(1)
#mydbobject = DbModel.gql("WHERE key=:1", int(row)).fetch(1)#invalid literal for int()   with base 10
#print mydbobject,row

que = db.Query(DbModel)
results = que.fetch(100)
mydbobject = None
for item in results:
if item.key().__str__() in row:
    mydbobject = item
```

EDIT1- one more attempt that does not retrieve the record, the key exists in the Datastore along with the record
    mydbobject = DbModel.gql("WHERE key = KEY('%s')"%row).fetch(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I correct in my assumption that you're basically just want to retrieve an object with a particular key? If so, the [get and get_by_id methods](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html) may be of help:

```
mydbobject = DbModel.get_by_id(int(self.request.get("selectedrow")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error "invalid literal for int()" indicate that the paramater pass to int was not a string representing an integer. Try to print the value of "row" for debuging, I bet it is an empty string.

The correct way to retrieve an element from the key is simply by using the method "get" or "get_by_id".
In your case:

```
row = self.request.get("selectedrow")
mydbobject = DbModel.get(row)
```

Comment: row contains key when dumped and not empty, but get works, thx so much